# How to have a public AWS CodeArtifact Repository policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, repository, policy, aws-codeartifact

Is it possible to make a repository inside AWS CodeArtifact public without any credentials required?

I tried this repository policy, but didn't work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:DescribePackageVersion",
                "codeartifact:DescribeRepository",
                "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionReadme",
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionAssets",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionDependencies",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersions",
                "codeartifact:ListPackages",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "didn't work" - is not specific. What exactly did you try, how did you test it, and what results did you get (error messages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66365401/2359762

which says:

> Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible at the time of the writing.

Also, there is only one Gradle plugin that allows generating the token and we couldn't make it work in the Android project.
https://github.com/clarityai-eng/codeartifact-gradle-plugin

For our specific use-case, we switched to GitHub Packages.